# Touch-optimized paint program

Tags: windows, images, image-editor, drawing

We're on vacation and it's raining :-( My kids want to paint some pictures, but unfortunately, we didn't bring pencils with us. My laptop has multitouch and we started using Paint.NET, which works quite well. It's fascinating for them that you can undo mispainted strokes and that you can paint over already painted areas.

[image: Child picture]

But Paint.NET has some disadvantages for children:

- The color picker makes it hard to pick dark colors. My son would prefer e.g. two color wheels, one with white in the middle and one with black in the middle. Of course, it is possible to pick dark colors in the extended view, but it's too complex then.

  [image: PDN Color Picker]
- The eraser erases to transparency. Transparency seems to be hard to understand. Transparency does not need to be supported.
- Paint.NET's tool windows often overlap the picture, so you need to move them away. I guess it would be simpler to have the tool windows docked (which is IMHO not possible in Paint.NET)

  [image: Overlap issue]
- The object modifier points are too small and hard to touch in Paint.NET. This should be more touch-friendly.

  [image: Object modifier points]
- Ideally the UI would be configurable so that I can remove everything that I have not explained yet.
- Such a Paint.NET alternative would need to run on Windows 10 and not be a Windows Store app (I don't have and I don't want an account)
- File formats are not important. I guess it will support at least one common format.
- Undo/Redo in virtually unlimited number is a must-have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long, long, long time ago, I've used an application TuxPaint. It's an extremely easy to use painting/drawing application designed for children and appears to have a very easy to use UI. It also has very large buttons so in regard to touch screens, this should be perfect. Some features you requested:

- It's available on a wide variety of OS's including windows 95-10, OS X, & Linux. The color picker has simple buttons for colors so no scrolling through colors or using RGB to pick them.
- Doesn't look like it supports transparency so I don't think that may be a problem with the eraser. Object modifiers aren't supported for increase ease of use.
- I don't think you can change the UI as the UI is pretty simple and designed for exactly what you're trying to do.
- Undo and Redo are supported.
- [A lot of other cool features too are available](http://www.tuxpaint.org/features/).

## [Tux Paint](http://www.tuxpaint.org/)

#### Open Source Drawing Software for Children

> Tux Paint is a free, award-winning drawing program for children ages 3 to 12 (for example, preschool and K-6). Tux Paint is used in schools around the world as a computer literacy drawing activity. It combines an easy-to-use interface, fun sound effects, and an encouraging cartoon mascot who guides children as they use the program.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Quite nice. It has a few issues in windowed mode, but full-screen is fine.

Comment: Undo is not so unlimited. We have reached the limit quite often. But anyway, it's much fun for the children, especially the magic effects.